# Scala type inference for existential types and type members

Tags: scala, type-inference, existential-type, type-members

The following piece of code does not compile :

```
trait A[F] {
  def find(x: Int): F
  def fill(f: F): Unit
}

object TestA {
  def test[T <: A[F] forSome { type F }](t: T) =
    t.fill(t.find(0))
}
```

It returns the following compilation error :

```
test.scala:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)F(in type T)
 required: F(in type T)
    t.fill(t.find(0))
                 ^
```

However the following code complies just fine :

```
trait B[F] {
  type R = F
  def find(x: Int): R
  def fill(f: R): Unit
}

object TestB {
  def test[T <: B[F] forSome { type F }](t: T) =
    t.fill(t.find(0))
}
```

I have two questions here :

1. I expect the fist piece of code to compile. Why does it not?
2. If there is a good reason why first piece of code does not compile, I would expect the second to not compile either, for the same reason. How then, does it compile successfully?

Is either of these a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the compiler differentiates the two pieces of code. Basically, the code doesn't compile because the type returned by `find` and the type expected by `fill` don't have to be the same `F`, at least if `find` and `fill` were called on two different objects.

You could make the first piece of code to compile with:

```
def test[T <: A[F], F](t: T) =
  t.fill(t.find(0))
```

And you could make the second piece of code not to compile with:

```
def test[T <: B[F] forSome { type F }](t: T, u: T) =
  t.fill(u.find(0))
```

This should be rather a comment than an answer, but I don't have 50 reputation yet.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what's happening, let's look at simpler versions of `TestA.test` and `TestB.test`.

```
object TestA {
  def test1(a: A[String]) = {
    val s: String = a.find(0)
    a.fill(s)
  }
}

object TestB {
  def test1(b: B[String]) = {
    val r: b.R = b.find(0)
    b.fill(r)
  }
}
```

Notice how the type of the intermediate value `s` refers to `String`, while the type of the intermediate value `r` does not.

```
object TestA {
  def test2(a: A[F] forSome {type F}) = {
    val s: F forSome {type F} = a.find(0)

    // type mismatch;
    //   found   : s.type (with underlying type F forSome { type F })
    //   required: F
    a.fill(s)
  }
}

object TestB {
  def test2(b: B[F] forSome {type F}) = {
    val r: b.R = b.find(0)
    b.fill(r)
  }
}
```

Once we throw in the existentials, we end up with an intermediate value `s` whose type is equivalent to `Any`, and which thus isn't a valid input for `a.fill`. The intermediate type for `r`, however, is still `b.R`, and so it is still an appropriate input for `b.fill`. The reason its type is still `b.R` is because `b.R` doesn't refer to `F`, and so according to [the simplification rules for existential types](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#simplification-rules), `b.R forSome {type F}` is equivalent to `b.R`, in the same way that `Int forSome {type F}` is equivalent to `Int`.

> Is either of these a bug?

Well, there is certainly a bug somewhere (as of scalac 2.11.7), because the following does not type check.

```
object TestB {
  def test3(b: B[F] forSome {type F}) = {
    val r: b.R forSome {type F} = b.find(0)

    // type mismatch;
    //   found   : F
    //   required: b.R
    //     (which expands to)  F
    b.fill(r)
  }
}
```

So either I'm wrong to think that `b.R` does not refer to `F`, in which case `b.R forSome {type F}` is not equivalent to `b.R` and your `TestB.test` should not type check but it does, or `b.R forSome {type F}` is equivalalent to `b.R`, in which case my `TestB.test3` should type check but it doesn't.

I'm quite convinced that the bug is with the latter, because the error even occurs when the existential quantification has nothing to do with `b.R`, as in the following example.

```
object TestB {
  def test4(b: B[F] forSome {type F}) = {
    val r: b.R forSome {val x: Int} = b.find(0)

    // type mismatch;
    //   found   : F
    //   required: b.R
    //     (which expands to)  F
    b.fill(r)
  }
}
```