# Scala type check

Tags: scala, typechecking

How to make this typecheck?

```
trait Test[A] {
  type Output = A
  def get: Iterable[A]
  def check(a: A): Boolean
}

object A {
  def fs: List[Test[_]] = ???
  def test = for{f <- fs
    a <- f.get
    if f.check(a)} println(a)
}
```

It complains with

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type _$1)
 required: _$1
           if f.check(a)} println(a)
```

### Attempt #1 (failed)

```
object A {
  def fs: List[Test[_]] = ???
  def test = for{f <- fs
    a <- f.get
    if f.check(a.asInstanceOf[f.Output])} println(a)
}
```

but then I have the same problem:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : f.Output
    (which expands to)  _$1
 required: _$1
               if f.check(a.asInstanceOf[f.Output])} println(a)
```

### Attempt #2 (failed)

Having learned of some existential types, I am trying to replace the underscore -- at Test level, because not all A may be identical

```
object A {
  def fs: List[Test[A] forSome { type A }] = ???
  def test = for{f <- fs
    a <- f.get
    if f.check(a)} println(a)
}
```

It complains with:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
           if f.check(a)} println(a)
```

How to get out of this type nightmare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that the Scala compiler doesn't notice that the types hidden by the existential must be the same.

There are two solutions:

1. Make a single method calling both `get` and `check`:

   ```
   object A {
     private def getChecked[A](f: Test[A]) = f.get.withFilter(f.check)

     def fs: List[Test[_]] = ???
     def test = for { f <- fs; a <- getChecked(f) } println(a)
   ```
2. Give name to the existential using a type variable pattern. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work inside a `for`, so you'll need to desugar it first:

   ```
   // equivalent to your initial code
   def test = fs.flatMap { f => f.get.withFilter { a => f.check(a) } }.
                 foreach { a => println(a) }

   // with a type variable
   def test = fs.flatMap { case f: Test[x] => f.get.withFilter { a => f.check(a) } }.
                 foreach { a => println(a) }
   ```

Comment: The first method works great thanks. I was able to remove all casting clutter. I bet that the second method works as well but since the real for-loop is much bigger than just get check, it would be counter-productive to desugar it. But it's nice to see that there is a solution. Are you aware of any future improvement of Scala which may allow to have this behavior directly inside a for-loop?

Comment: No, but you may want to report it on Scala mailing list or in https://issues.scala-lang.org/. The version I would expect to work is `for { f: Test[x] <- fs ...`

Comment: Oh actually by replacing the last two `A` in class `Test` by `Output`, it compiles just fine. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649279/scala-type-inference-for-existential-types-and-type-members

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to push the existential type *inside*.

```
object A {
  def fs: List[Test[A forSome { type A }]] = ???
  def test = for{f <- fs
    a <- f.get
    if f.check(a)} println(a)
}
```

And voilà it worked out.

Comment: Unfortunately, `A forSome { type A }` is basically just `Any`, so once you try to actually define `fs` you'll run into trouble.

Comment: You're right, I ran into trouble, but in this case I was able to force type-checking by casting each element of the fs using `.asInstanceOf[Test[A forSome { type A }]]`